# Making the card game 21 in python

Tags: python

```
Hand1 = []
Hand2 = []

import random
Card1 = (random.choice(cardList))
Hand1.append(Card1)
cardList.remove(Card1)

Card1 = (random.choice(cardList))
Hand1.append(Card1)
cardList.remove(Card1)

#print(Hand1)
total = 0
for i in Hand1:
    ("player one picked the",Hand1[0],"of",Hand1[2],"and the",Hand1[3],"of",Hand1[5])
    total = total + i[1]
```

this code is giving me a list index out of range error and I don't understand why. above this code there is a very long list of all the cards in a deck. please help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What's the error message?

Comment: it will be clearer if you print the exact error you get. That's the use of this error! :)

Comment: this is the exact error:

Comment: Well, Hand1 is shorter than 6. So Hand1 is a list of lists? Maybe you wanted to have i[5] instead of Hand1[5]?

Comment: ... and probably you just mean 4 in the last index, would better fit to 0, 1, 2, 3 ;)

Comment: ("player one picked the",Hand1[0],"of",Hand1[2],"and the",Hand1[3],"of",Hand1[5])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: changing Hand1 into I didn't seem to work and the reason for the indexs are like that is because my card list is like this:

Comment: [["Ace",1,"Hearts"],["2",2,"Hearts"],["3",3,"Hearts"]

Comment: your list Hand1 has only length 3 - it has not 9 elements but 3, each of which is a list of 3. That's the clue

Comment: thanks that has solved my problem perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

means, your List is too short and does not have the desired index (obviusly index 5 is the problem). Are you sure, that you have 6 elements in `Hand1`?

Probably you just mean the index 4 there.

Generally, you should add more `print` statements to see, what your variables are.

---

Edit after your comment:
ah, then your Hand 1 is a list of lists. you want to have the elements

```
Hand1[0][0] of Hand1[0][2] and Hand1[1][0] of Hand1[1][2]
```